# Tools to measure image angle cut

Tags: image-processing

Wanted to know if there any tools using which i could measure the angle cut an image is showing

As i want to check after applying css to a image if they angle it provides is correct or not

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us the original image that you're going to work with? (without the purple line)

Comment: Can you provide a real image, not a diagram ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this angle out using https://www.ginifab.com/feeds/angle_measurement/